# How to write ROS integration tests?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you write ROS integration tests, where you simulate a running node?

I've written some custom ROS nodes, and now I want to create some automated tests to confirm that they publish certain messages in response to receiving certain messages. [These docs](https://wiki.ros.org/unittest#ROS-Node-Level_Integration_Tests) briefly mention integration tests and running tests "as a node", but they don't make any sense to me. The example given doesn't actually test the node, and only runs a toy `self.assertEquals(1, 1)`.

For my test, I want to start roscore, several dependency nodes, my custom node, then publish messages, then wait N seconds for my node to publish its own messages, and fail if this doesn't happen. Is there any documentation on how to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285903/how-to-write-ros-integration-tests?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-05**:
[Exmaple of integration with ROS / MAVROS](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/test_and_ci/integration_testing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2019-06-23**:
That's is not an answer. Its a framework that has no examples on how to write a test

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
The first link under the *Overview* section is [Writing rostests](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest/Writing). Does that not provide sufficient information to at least get started?

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2019-06-24**:
No. It shows how to do gtest which is a unit test. An example of ROSTest(integration test) is not shown. Again the framework on how set set it up in the CMakefile.txt is shown but the actually writing of the test node is not.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
The OP specifically asked:

> For my test, I want to start roscore, several dependency nodes, my custom node, then publish messages, then wait N seconds for my node to publish its own messages, and fail if this doesn't happen.

rostest is how you do that. The [rostest/Nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest/Nodes) page shows how to create `.test` files (essentially `.launch` files) that test what the OP appeared to ask for.

That's why I posted this answer.

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2019-06-24**:
Yes it does , but it does not tell you how to create the tester node. The tester node would have to publish messages to get the test started. I would assume the tester node would also have to subscribe to the result to determine that it occurred. There is no example on how to publish or subscribe and check for the result.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
I don't believe that's how it works.

The "tester nodes" in the examples are already provided as part of the *Standard Test Nodes* ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/29053c4832229efa7160fb944c05e3bc82e11540/tools/rostest/nodes)).

> The tester node would have to publish messages to get the test started.

That depends on what is getting tested: if the node-under-test is a subscriber, you'd have to write a small node that publishes messages, yes. Nothing special about that I believe.

If the NUT is a publisher, the provided standard test nodes could be used, at least as a starting point.

See [rostest/nodes/publishtest](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/29053c4832229efa7160fb944c05e3bc82e11540/tools/rostest/nodes/publishtest#L36-L54) as an example fi.

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2019-06-24**:
Now we are getting closer to an answer.

Using your above scenario if the node-under-test is a subscriber it would do some kind transformation/algorithm and output something. How would you know that the output is correct? In order fro an integration test to be valid you need to set up the test conditions and then verify that the results you are getting are correct. Having a test node publish the starting conditions is nothing special, but then you still have to verify the results.